# How to use PagedListAdapter with multiple LiveData(s)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-paging

I have a recycler view with a **PagedListAdapter**.

In **onCreate** I have this code:

```
 viewModel.recentPhotos.observe(this, Observer<PagedList<Photo>> {
            photoAdapter.submitList(it)
        })
```

**recentPhotos** is initialized in this way:

```
val recentPhotosDataSource = RecentPhotosDataSourceFactory(ApiClient.INSTANCE.photosClient)

        val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE)
                .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
                .build()

        recentPhotos = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Photo>(recentPhotosDataSource, pagedListConfig)
                .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build()
```

And it works fine.

Next, I have **search()** function:

```
private fun searchPhotos(query: String) {
        viewModel.recentPhotos.removeObservers(this)

        viewModel.searchPhotos(query)?.observe(this, Observer {
            photoAdapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }
```

**viewModel.searchPhotos** looks like this:

```
   fun searchPhotos(query: String): LiveData<PagedList<Photo>>? {
        val queryTrimmed = query.trim()

        if (queryTrimmed.isEmpty()) {
            return null
        }

        val dataSourceFactory = SearchPhotosDataSourceFactory(ApiClient.INSTANCE.photosClient, queryTrimmed)

        val livePagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, PAGE_SIZE)
                .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build()

        return livePagedList
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I have an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AsyncPagedListDiffer cannot handle both contiguous and non-contiguous lists.
```

My question is can I use one recycler view and one adapter for multiple/different LiveData? And what is the best solution for my task when I have one recycler and I need to use it either for recent items or for search?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution...

Comment: Looks like your `recentPhotosDataSource` is coming from Room db. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is because you are asking the `AsyncPagedListDiffer` class to compare two differently constructed lists.

In creating `recentPhotos`, you use a `PagedList.Config`. However, in your `searchPhotos` function, you construct the `LiveData<PagedList>` using only the page size. Paging library has to compare these two lists. With your configuration, they cannot be compared.

I would suggest that you use construct the lists in a similar manner, either by using a `PagedList.Config` object or just a page size.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `recentPhotosDataSource` is coming from Room db. Am I right?
Room db creates `TiledPagedList` but your `SearchPhotosDataSourceFactory` which extends `PageKeyedDataSource`(or other datasource) creates `ContiguousPagedList`. That's why you got this error.

So I suppose the solution will be to create a new list adapter to show search results.